# Asterisk not adding CDR record in DB for call to unregistered peer

Tags: asterisk

I configured Asterisk CDR backend to PostgreSQL, and everything is working fine for calls between two registered peers.

The problem is when a user calls an unregistered peer. I want Asterisk to insert that record, but it doesn't (it responds to the caller's SIP client with 503 / Service Unavailable... maybe that has something to do with it).

I suspect the problem may be in the way I configured users registration, but I'm not an expert so I don't really know what I'm doing. Anyway, I'm reporting any information I deem useful to solve the problem, if I miss something important please ask and I will add it. I'm using Asterisk 13.

`cdr.conf`:

```
[general]
unanswered = yes
```

`extensions.conf`:

```
[default]
switch => Realtime/default@extensions
```

Pjsip peers and extensions are taken as well from the DB.

Example record in `asterisk.ps_endpoints`:

```
(id=100, transport=transport-udp, aors=100, auth=100, context=default, disallow=all, allow=ulaw, direct_media=no, identify_by=username, rtp_timeout=10)
```

Example record in `asterisk.ps_aors`:

```
(id=100, max_contacts=1, remove_existing=yes, qualify_frequency=10)
```

Example record in `asterisk.ps_auths`:

```
(id=100, auth_type=userpass, password=*****, username=100)
```

Example record in `asterisk.extensions`:

```
(id=7, context=default, exten=100, priority=1, app=Dial, appdata=PJSIP/100)
```

Notes:

- The table `asterisk.extensions` does not contain anything else except for the Dials.
- Non specified fields in the examples above are NULL.
- I'd prefer a solution that does not entail adding more records in `asterisk.extensions` *for each user* (but I have no problem adding a bunch of "static" new extensions).

Comment: When you dial to an unregistered peer, it's not a real call and then it is not registered in CDR.

Comment: So it's not possible to record calls to unregistered peers?

Comment: It's not possible. There is an alternative to CDR called **CEL** that is more detailed. Maybe with [CEL](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5242932) you can have the information that you want.